# Upload file to google drive results in bad request error message

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, httpclient

I am trying to upload an image file to Google drive with my asp.net MVC project.  I am using the Google drive v2 api but I can't upload the file.

I have tested this with PostMan and  that's working fine

## working in Postman

[image]

## my code

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

                using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
                    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("file")
                    {
                        FileName = "index.jpg"
                    };
                    content.Add(fileContent);

                    var requestUri = "/upload/drive/v2/files/" + FileId;
                    var result = client.PutAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
                }
            }
```

## Error:

My code is returning a bad request error and im not sure why.

[image]

Comment: Don't put HttpClient in a using block. [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient). Also don't use `.Result` for async operations. make your methods `async Task` and `await` the call. Please give a [mcve] and explain more on what's going wrong. Do you get an error?Exception? Other?

Comment: dear I have facing a bad request message, kindly check the snap

Comment: Don't put text in images. Just look at the image: the messages are truncated in the image... (p.s. remove all sensitive data)

Comment: p.s., why aren't you using the .NET Google API Library?

Comment: 1. why are you using google drive v2?.

Comment: If you want to insert a file, not update it, you should use a `POST` request, not `PUT`. Also, as others said, why not using the official library nor v3?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend that you use the [Google .net client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client), i also recommend that you switch to using [Google Drive v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk).

Assuming you agree to the above

First you will need to create a drive service all of your calls to the api will go through this.

```
// Create the  Drive service.
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential
    });
```

Assuming that your file does not already existing on Google drive you will do a file.create.  The first thing you need to do is create the metadata for the file.

```
// Upload file Metadata
var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
    {
    Name = "Test hello uploaded.txt",
    Parents = new List() {"10krlloIS2i_2u_ewkdv3_1NqcpmWSL1w"}
    };
```

Once that is uploaded you can upload the file stream

```
string uploadedFileId;
// Create a new file on Google Drive
await using (var fsSource = new FileStream(UploadFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
      // Create a new file, with metadata and stream.
      var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fsSource, "text/plain");
      request.Fields = "*";
      var results = await request.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

      if (results.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
         {
         Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {results.Exception.Message}");
         }

          // the file id of the new file we created
          uploadedFileId = request.ResponseBody?.Id;
      }
```

If the file actually already exists you will need to do a file .update and not a file.create.

I have a full blog post on how to upload files to Google drive with C# .net [How to upload a file to Google Drive with C# .net](https://www.daimto.com/upload-file-to-google-drive/) The authorization method for the tutial is service account you will need to use [web-applications-asp.net-mvc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc) this for your authorization.

If would rather video tutorial i have a video on the topic as well [Google Drive API V3: Complete guide to creating, updating and uploading files with a service account](https://youtu.be/Q5b0ivBYqeQ)

## your code

If you want to know what the issue is with your code then you might want to look into the diffrence between PutAsync and PostAsync.

```
var result = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dear @DaimTo, But I need an HTTP request solution through httpclient

Comment: You understand that the Client library probably does do that internally right?   Did you try changing it to PostAsync?